# open word document when running service

Tags: c#-4.0

I have written the following statement to open the word document.

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\\urvashi");
objMyDoc = ApObj.Documents.Open(filename, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\\komal");
```

It is working fine when I am checking it by debugging the code, but when running this code through the service it is not working properly.

It is creating directory "urvashi" in D drive but it is not creating directory "komal"  in D drive.

The error is in the second statment when running service; what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

"Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and **NT Services**), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?fr=1

Answer (score 0):

Office application can run in interactive mode not in service mode. so it is not advisable open any office documents in services / server side programs.

Comment: There is one window service into my local machine which scan the folder and if .doc file is available there it reads the document form local system. it was working properly but now its not working. Dont know what is the reason?